# SQL MAX GROUP BY returns null column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running this query:

```
SELECT t2.ID, MAX(t2.col1) 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.key = t2.key 
GROUP BY t2.key;
```

returns this result:

```
key 
ID1 0
ID2 1
```

I expected to get this however:

```
key col1 
ID1 0
ID2 1
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `MAX(t2.col1)  AS col1` or something similar. The syntax is depending on the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: microsoft sql server yeah that works thanks

Answer (score 1):

`MAX(t2.col1)  AS col1` or something similar. The syntax is depending on the RDBMS you are using. This is because most RDBMS will not auto generate a column name/alias for an expression, you must provide one if the column name/alias is important in the result set.